# Azure function 1.0 Logging

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using azure function with ILogger to log exception and tracing in Application Insights. I use log.LogError with an exception object as a second parameter. However, whatever log it only comes under traces in app insights and doesn't logs the entire exception object. Is there a way to get exception object with the entire stack?

Also, the dependency is empty and I make multiple HTTP calls and I am expecting it to log all HTTP calls as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The `LogError` extension method takes the [exception object as the *first* parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.logerror?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_LoggerExtensions_LogError_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILogger_System_Exception_System_String_System_Object___). Give that a try and your Exception object should show up correctly in App Insights.

```
public static void LogError (this Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger, Exception exception, string message, params object[] args);
```